# RExcel with Jdbc

Tags: r, excel, jdbc

I am trying for a jbbc connection through RExcel. The command

```
install.packages("RJDBC", dep=TRUE)
```

in RExcel shows downloading package but when run

```
library(RJDBC)
```

it shows

```
Error in library(RJDBC) : there is no package called ‘RJDBC’
```

which means that RJDBC has not been installed.

- Is it the proper way to install package in RExcel?
- Is there any way to check what packages are installed there in RExcel as I do not see any library folder in the working directory?
- Any alternate way to achieve JDBC connectivity through RExcel?

**Output of install process:**

```
[10] WARNING: Warning: cannot remove prior installation of package 'RJDBC'
[11] NOTE: trying URL 'http://ftp.iitm.ac.in/cran/bin/windows/contrib/3.1/RJDBC_0.2-5.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 65639 bytes (64 Kb)
opened URL
downloaded 64 Kb

package 'RJDBC' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\Leo\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpOo7HHY\downloaded_packages
```

Comment: See [How should I deal with “package 'xxx' is not available” warning?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25721884/602276)

Comment: @Andrie...now I got the answer of my 2nd question. The main concern is installing rjdbc.

Comment: It would seem the installation of `RJDBC` fails. Can you provide the whole output of the install process? Have you tried installing it in "raw" R?

Comment: In "raw" R it is installed successfully and I can perform jdbc operations from there...I have updated my question with the output of install process.

Comment: [Solved]
I removed the RJDBC package from "raw" R's library and then able to  install it in RExcel.